# apt-get broken after libboost error

Tags: apt

I seem to accedently have destroyed the libboost package somehow and now I am unable to use apt-get anymore.

I am at a loss of what to do here.

When I try to install something with apt-get I get the error:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libboost-serialization1.42-dev' missing,assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libboost-regex1.42-dev' missing,    assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libboost-iostreams-dev' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 55%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package `linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

(and some more packages from libboost-all-dev that is missing).

If I do

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

I get the result

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Is there any way I can rebuild and fix the missing packages?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install -f`, by the way according to this informations the only thing that doesn't works is `dpkg`

Comment: Thanks. Tired that with no success. I am staring to get very strange segfaults all over the place now (irssi just sefaulted to death and now apt-get returned segfault. Starting to suspect a disc crash.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using exactly

Comment: 11.04 [...........]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're sorry, but Ubuntu 10.04 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.